# JAX-WS: Dynamic Providers

Tags: java, jax-ws

I have an environment which hosts a number of "services" with inputs and outputs that are easily bound to XML. I want to be able to expose one or more services dynamically through SOAP. In other words, the user must be able to combine service A and B into a webservice (and optionally configure names etc for the operations).

This means I need to be able to dynamically generate the WSDL or at least parts of it (especially the XSD definitions which can be requested from the services) and I need to be able to dynamically create and publish new endpoints which all use a single Provider class which (based on context and what not) will determine which service you are trying to invoke. It will unmarshal the XML, call the service, marshal the response and send that back.

Is this possible with JAX-WS? I would very much like to take advantage of the existing features (notably WS-* etc) that come with JAX-WS. If it is not possible with JAX-WS, are there any other options?

Answer (score 2):

Your use case is actually very hard to implement with JAX-WS (and maybe even impossible). But do not worry, you are not the first one with this requirement.

Imagine a big company with several legacy systems that need to be integrated. Then they spent a lot of money and time implementing an SOA architecture based on SOAP web services. These services are combined (orchestred) to create business process.

**Example:** The business process 'Create a contract' needs the execution of the web services A, B and C.

But what happen if changing the business process needs some code source changes??? The company needs to have a development team keeping those process up-to-day.

To solve this, **BPEL's dynamic binding** was created. This technology allows you to compose a new service at runtime based on the parameters of the requested service!

In a few words, what you need to do if define several 'base web services' and then configure a BPEL server to dynamically combined those services at runtime!

Please read [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/carey-090553.html) from Oracle to get an idea ...

And check here the [JBoss BPEL user guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/4.0/html-single/JBoss_BPEL_User_Guide/index.html).

**What you should do to use BPEL in your case**

- Create SOAP a web service for each of your non-soap services (lets call this 'base webservices').
- Configure a BPEL engine to orchestrate the composition/combination of the 'base web services'.
- Create clients capable to composes/combines the 'base web services' at runtime (per each request if needed) using the BPEL endpoint. *NOTE: this do not need changes in the BPEL engine configuration*

With this, you will have a very powerful platform to do orchestration that you can extend for more complex use cases in the future.

Hope it helps ...

Comment: As I understand it, BPEL is indeed an orchestration engine used to create a business flow using webservices. However the business flows already exist in the services, I merely need to expose the "root" services of said business processes through SOAP so they can be triggered externally. Additionally the creation and management of said webservices must be fully programmatic.

Comment: BPEL can have pre-fixed workflows (as you described) or dynamic workflows based on dynamic bindings. This last one allows change the workflow based on the request. Now, *Change the workflow* means combine different 'base' web services at runtime (this is what you need right?). For the client of a BPEL service it will call a single 'root' SOAP web service (actually, the client will not know that is executing a BPEL workflow).

Comment: The only thing that BPEL doesn't offer you is the 'fully programatic' root web service. But I do not get why you need that: there is nothing that you can do with JAX-WS that you cannot do with the XML descriptor of a BPEL workflow (regarding your use case). I strongly recommend you to read more about BPEL (and test it!) before trying to re-invent a BPEL engine by yourself, because satisfying your requirement is why BPEL was created for ...

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand the use of BPEL in this case. I have a fully functioning service with endpoints that are described in XSD and have input/output that can be easily marshalled to XML. The only thing I need to add is some SOAP handling, preferably with some neat WS-* options. BPEL does way more than that though, no?

Comment: I need the programmatic interface because the user must go through our system to set up a webservice, not through an external tool or configuration files. It needs to integrate with the rest of the system.

Comment: Yes, BPEL do a lot more, but it can help you in your requirement. Dynamic bindings does not need changes in configuration files. The user can go through all your web service definitions and combine them at runtime (using a SOAP request). A BPEL engine  can be considered as a 'external system', but it is not: you declare your web services and the engine will help you to orchestrate them (statically or dynamically), and it can be deployed in the same server (or not). For the client perspective, BEPL endpoint is another service from your application.

Comment: It true that BPEL is a big thing, and is easy to get lost but do a test of dynamic bindings to see if you can implement your SOAP handling + all WS-* options. I'm pretty sure that it will be easier than publishing services dynamically with JAX-WS

Comment: I add more info to my answer. Hoping it helps.

Answer (score 1):

One good way is to use a CDM as your payload structure. In CDM (Common Data Model), you define the extensible schema that can absorb any XML type.

Conventional XML:

```
<dataset> 
            <BillingAddress>
                 <set>
                     <po-box >22224<po-box>
                     <suburb   code="2009">Pyrmont</suburb>
                     <city  >Sydney</city>
                     <country  code="AU">Australia</country>
                </set>
            </BillingAddress>
            <OfficeAddress>
                 <set>
                      <street >2/73 Union St</street>
                     <suburb   code="2009">Pyrmont</suburb>
                     <city  >Sydney</city>
                     <country   code="AU">Australia</country>
               </set>
            </OfficeAddress> 
</dataset>
```

Common Data Model XML:

```
<objects>
  <object is="Address">
       <set>
             <text is="suburb"  code="2009">Pyrmont</text>
             <text is="city">Sydney</text>
             <text is="country" code="AU">Australia</text>

            <object is="BillingAddress">
                 <set>
                     <text is="po-box.billing">22224<text>
                     <text is="suburb.billing" code="2009">Pyrmont</text>
                     <text is="city.billing">Sydney</text>
                     <text is="country.billing" code="AU">Australia</text>
                </set>
            </object>
            <object is="OfficeAddress">
                 <set>
                      <text is="street.office">2/73 Union St<text>
                     <text is="suburb.office"  code="2009">Pyrmont</text>
                     <text is="city.office">Sydney</text>
                     <text is="country.office" code="AU">Australia</text>
               </set>
            </object>
         </set>
    </object>
</objects>
```

The main service can take the CDM and based on a certain flag in the XML, it can route the request to the appropriate Web service.

This is just my thought. You need to build on top of this.

Comment: Some of the services deal with CDMs actually :) It is not possible to wrap some of the inputs/outputs as they are designed for a very specific goal. They must remain as is and simply be exposed through SOAP.